# divisibility relations in sets.

Tags: divisibility

How to draw an arrow diagram, a digraph and the matrix representation for the specified relation? The "divides" relation $|$ from the set $\{0,1,2\}$ to the set $\{0,3,6,9\}$

Comment: First: write down the relation as a subset of $\{ 0,1,2 \} \times \{ 0,3,6,9 \}$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$